# duplicate data in Volley NetworkResponse

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I used the following code to request and cache in the volley

```java
    public class CacheRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public CacheRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
        if (cacheEntry == null) {
            cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
        }
        final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
        final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
        final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
        cacheEntry.data = response.data;
        cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
        cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
        String headerValue;
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
        return Response.success(response, cacheEntry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

But
My data from the server response is repeated.

Server return this result:

```
{
    "id":12,
    "channel_id":7,
    "category_id":8
}
```

Cache mechanism return :

```
{
    "id":12,
    "channel_id":7,
    "category_id":8
},
{
    "id":12, 
    "channel_id":7,
    "category_id":8
}
```